# Upgrade artifacts limit on DevOps will impact existing pipelines and configuration?

Tags: angular, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, cicd, azure-artifacts

When I run pipelines on Azure DevOps, I am facing error 402 Payment Required - GET https://pkgs.dev.azure.com..... and npm install failed.

Artifacts free limit 2GB is exceeded, so I am facing this issue due to artifacts limit exceeded?

Also, if I upgrade free artifacts limit then it will impact existing pipelines and configuration.

Do let me know if you need any further details?

Appreciate your detailed guidance regarding this issue.

Thanks.

Expecting solutions of this Azure pipeline issue. Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure Artifact will have limitation of 2GiB free storage: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/devops/azure-devops-services/

[image]

If you would like to pay for additional storage space, set up billing for your DevOps organization first: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/billing/set-up-billing-for-your-organization-vs?view=azure-devops

By upgrading your free artifacts limit, this action will **not** impact pipelines and configuration. Refer to this official doc for Azure Artifacts management: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/start-using-azure-artifacts?view=azure-devops

Comment: Thanks for sharing helpful information.

Comment: Again thanks for your valuable answer, I would like to confirm that I have tried on devops and above answer is true that "By upgrading your free artifacts limit, this action will not impact pipelines and configuration."